# Extension not opening multiple links in new tab once uploaded to the chrome app store

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm trying to make a personal Chrome extension with tabs to my most visited websites. I have a large border to the side of my tabs that I want to use as a button, which will open every link in a new tab when pressed.

I currently have the button set as this:

```
<button class="left-button" onclick="topLeft()"></button>
```

I have some JavaScript setup like this:

```
function topLeft() {
  window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
  window.open('https://www.reddit.com');
  window.open('https://www.facebook.com');
  window.open('https://outlook.live.com');
};
```

The above works perfectly before uploading it as an extension to Chrome (as in it works fine when run locally). Once it's uploaded as an extension, the button can be pressed, but nothing happens.

I have tried replacing my

```
window.open('url');
```

With

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "myurls" });
```

But the results were unsuccessful.

My manifest.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "my extension",
  "description": "A Homepage extension.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": ["tabs"],

  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
      "newtab" : "index.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For chrome extension, by default [Inline JavaScript will not be executed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution), that means `onLeft` method won't be triggered for the following line.

```
<button class="left-button" onclick="topLeft()"></button>
```

Please try the following way to bind click handler:

```
<button id="LEFT_BUTTON_ID" class="left-button" onclick="topLeft()"></button>

document.getElementById('LEFT_BUTTON_ID').addEventListener('click', topLeft);
```

Comment: I would remove the `onclick="topLeft()"` in the HTML tag